# How to preserve input data from a waitForTaskToken step to the next step

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

I have the following stepfunction:

```
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    MyStateMachine:
      name: MyStateMachine    
      definition:
        StartAt: StateA
        States:
           StateA:
             Type: Task
             Resource:
               Fn::GetAtt: [LambdaA, Arn]
             Next: StateB
           StateB:
             Type: Task
             Resource: 'arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken'
             Parameters:
               FunctionName:
                 Fn::GetAtt: [ LambdaB, Arn ]
               Payload:
                 input.$: '$'
                 taskToken.$: '$$.Task.Token'
              TimeoutSeconds: 300
              OutputPath: '$'
            Next: StateC
          StateC:
            Type: Task
            Resource:
              Fn::GetAtt: [LambdaC, Arn]
            End: true
```

`LambdaB` is returning the input data from `StateB` including the generated Tasktoken.
However when `send-task-token-success` with this tasktoken and some additional data is called, the input data of `StateC` is only the data send with the `send-task-token-success` call.

Is there a way to pass along the output data from `StateB` to `StateC`?

Unfortunately I don't have any controll about the data send with the `send-task-token-success` and I need the information in `StateC` which data was used before the task token was generated.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found the solution.

Adding `ResultPath` to the step does the trick